# How to hide elements on one page with button on a different page, using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hide

I have a page with list items (links) that I need to be able to `hide/show` from my admin page.

How do I get it to work that if i press a button in my admin page, it hides list items that are on a different page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("a").css("display","none");
    });
});
</script>
```

The above code works to hide elements that are on the  same page only.

Comment: which elements do you want to hide on the other page? Can you use AJAX/PHP?

Comment: Are both pages loaded in the browser at the same time?

Comment: How are the items on the "other" pages being generated? The web server isn’t going to be creating those items for the "other" page while you’re on the admin page. I suspect you’ll need some sort of backend server-side language to accomplish this.

Comment: you need to create a server app which it will talk to the admin page and user page, check which elements are visible on the user page and when the admin hide them remove() them from the user page.. a webworker could do.. or setInverval() and call the ajax function to talk to server each time

Comment: I can use a bit of php, i have used ajax before, but i was pretty much given the code!

Comment: Both pages arent loaded at the same time..................The items are generated as a php 'include' in the header. They are not from a db though

Comment: @GlenRogers: Based on your response, I’m going to say go ahead and use jQuery to fire stuff as a `$.get` with params that set something in your PHP `$_SESSION` that tell the server to hide XYZ when it renders the "other" (non-admin) parts of the site later.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of ( using Client side scripting only)

Is to create a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) on click in the first page,

and in the 2nd page, when window gets focus after it loses it (meaning user left the page tab and got back to it), check for that cookie , if it's set then hide. or if you want the user to have it hidden already when he enters, on window blur start checking until window focuses.

You can use [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) (or regular js) and do
something like :

```
$("button").click(function(){
     $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
 });
```

And in page 2 :

```
$(window).focus(function(){
  if($.cookie('the_cookie') == "the_value"){
      $("a").hide();
      $.removeCookie('the_cookie'); // so i't won't happen again
  }
  else { //if it already was
      $("a").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: This will work, but is throwing security out the window and leaving everything in the hands of the user.

Comment: @Phillip he didn't mentioned security is important.

Comment: I know, just throwing my 2 cents in.